# Visual Studio: attribute 'nodiscard' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'

Tags: azerothcore

Im following this guide: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Installation
I am trying to compile build [6a95e61](https://github.com/55Honey/azerothcore-wotlk/commit/1ed80e95969ce672cdb8bd6d17de58cfb0785f6d) with no additional modules under win64 and get 439 identical errors. They point to different files after like half a minute when selecting build/build solution in Visual Studio:

`C2429    attribute 'nodiscard' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17' (compiling source file C:\Azerothcore\azerothcore\src\server\shared\DataStores\DBCDatabaseLoader.cpp) shared  c:\azerothcore\azerothcore\src\common\datastores\dbcfileloader.h    38`

[image]

A full wipe and starting over from git-bash yields the same results, so i guess im making mistakes in the process, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to the guys on azerothcore discord!
Steps which solved it for me:

- Uninstalling Visual Studio 2017 and cMake 3.8.2
- Installing Visual Studio 2019 with all dependancies in "Desktop Development with C++" and
- Installing cMake 3.19.2
- re-Built with cMake (as in the official guide)
- Build/Build Solution in Visual Studio (as in the official guide)